# How to make a call in ios swift 5 using UITextview?

Tags: xcode, uitextview, swift5

I having the UITextView with phone number. How to make a call when clicking on the phone number in the UITextView in ios Swift 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TextView provide one delegate method to get click event of any detector like phone number, link.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    if URL.scheme == "tel" {
        let phone = URL.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "tel:", with: "")

        if let callUrl = URL(string: "tel://\(phone)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(callUrl) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(callUrl)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Also don't forgot this.

```
textView.dataDetectorTypes = [.phoneNumber]
textView.delegate = self
```